# Creating a find method

Tags: c#, list, find, equals

I'm trying to create a find method from scratch to see if two objects are equal given that certain members are equal, using the Equals method to do so. I know using the Find/Contains methods would be faster, but I can't use them. The signature of the method is "static int Find(List c, Coffee x)" Find seeks x in c and returns a valid index (e.g., 0, 1) if x exists in c, returns -1 otherwise. The equals method must be used to determine equivalency. If the passed object isn't equal to a current object in a list, it is added to the list (the list contains two types of objects that derive from a base class, so the list can store both types). Equivalencyis defined by name, cost, demand, holding cost and roasttype for regular and name, cost, demand, holding cost and minimum quantity for decaf. Here's what I have so far:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create objects and references
        Coffee obv = new Coffee();
        Decaf decafCoffee = null;
        Regular regularCoffee = null;
        List<Coffee> inventory = new List<Coffee>();


        // Prompt user for input and store it as a string
        Console.Write("Enter q to quit or the whole data as a comma delimited string using the following format Name,D,C,D:minQ or R:roast ");
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        // Loop
        while (!s.ToLower().Equals("q"))
        {
            // Split string up and assign componets to variables
            string[] values = s.Split(",".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string name = values[0];
            string demand = (values[1]);
            string cost = (values[2]);
            string type = values[3];

            // Check for > 0 and convert to numbers
            float D = CheckDemand(demand);
            float C = CheckCost(cost);
            float M = 0;

            if (type.StartsWith("D:"))
            {
                type = Regex.Match(type, @"\d+").Value;
                M = CheckMin(type);
                decafCoffee = new Decaf(name, D, C, M);
                inventory.Add(decafCoffee);
            }

            else if (type.StartsWith("R:"))
            {
                if (type.Contains("light"))
                {
                    M = 1;
                    regularCoffee = new Regular(name, D, C, M);
                    inventory.Add(regularCoffee);
                }
                else if (type.Contains("medium"))
                {
                    M = 2;
                    regularCoffee = new Regular(name, D, C, M);
                    inventory.Add(regularCoffee);
                }

                else if (type.Contains("dark"))
                {
                    M = 3;
                    regularCoffee = new Regular(name, D, C, M);
                    inventory.Add(regularCoffee);
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("\nError, please enter all lower case \"dark\", \"medium\", or \"light\" next time.");
            }

            else Console.WriteLine("\nError, please enter either \"D:\" followed by a number or \"R:\" followed by roast type next time.");
            Console.Write("\nEnter q to quit or the whole data as a comma delimited string using the following format Name,D,C,D:minQ or R:roast: ");
            s = Console.ReadLine();
        }   // End loop

        // Sort and  display values
        var sortedList = inventory.OrderBy(i => i.Q()).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine("\nName \t   C ($)      Demand \t  Detail   Q(lbs.)     TAC
        for (int j = 0; j < inventory.Count; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", sortedList[j].toString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(obv.toStringQ());
```

This is what I have for the equals method:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Coffee)
        {
            bool isNameEqual = Name.Equals(this.Name);
            bool isuCostEqual = Cost.Equals(this.Cost);
            bool isDemandEqual = Demand.Equals(this.Demand);
            bool ishCostEqual = h.Equals(this.h);
            bool isMinEqual = getQ.Equals(this.getQ);

            return (isNameEqual && isuCostEqual && isDemandEqual && ishCostEqual && isMinEqual);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How do I go about using the find method?

Comment: You need to implement an equals comparator in the Coffee class.

Answer (score 1):

Implement an 'Equals' method on Coffee and optionally on its sub-classes such as Decaf, Regular, etc. Now you can directly use the `Contains` method on the list.

Comment: Yes, you would have to. Because the problem statement says: "Equivalency is defined by name, cost, demand, holding cost and roasttype for regular and name, cost, demand, holding cost and minimum quantity for decaf" - this should be taken into account while implementing the 'Equals' method. Let us know if you run into issues while implementing this. Good luck!